# Lightdm does not start at boot, it will start after stop/starting the service

Tags: boot, 16.04, kubuntu, lightdm, nvidia-prime

I am using lightdm on Kubuntu 16.04. And when I boot the system boots in to a non-gui login screen. In order to start lightdm I have to type:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop ; sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start
```

And then it starts normally. 
Is there a way to understand why its not starting right? 
I have no problem resetting lightdm settings if that might be the problem cause.

**Update:**
Ok I am pretty sure the problem started when I upgraded my nvidia drivers. Which I had to, because I am developing with it.

I pulled the lightdm.log of both the broken and working load.

Working config (after restarting):
http://pastebin.com/q89fVHXA

Failing config (on boot):
http://pastebin.com/y9uqm1Xs

I tried upgrading the nvidia drivers to nvidia-637 and nvidia-370 and no luck.
Also tried kernel 4.4.0 and 4.6.3, same result.
Googling I saw other people with a similar problem, but no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same occurred on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, but looking at my start log I saw an error with sddm. Maybe I installed it with kde-plasma, but I don't remember turning it on.

Just run `sudo apt remove sddm` and `lightdm start` at boot again.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it! And this was the first time I got this. Do you remember what log the sddm error came up in?